# is there an easy way to remember taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, classification

So I have trouble remembering the order of taxonomy for classification.
i.e domain>kingdom>phylum>class>order>family>genus>species

I can never remember it, is there an good mnemonic to remember them? How do you guys remember it?

Comment: Of course, Randall Munroe has a solution to your problem: https://xkcd.com/992/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Wikipedia > List of mnemonics#Biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mnemonics#Biology).

- **D**ear **K**ing **P**hilip **C**ame **O**ver **F**or **G**ood **S**oup
- **D**o **K**ings **P**lay **C**hess **O**n **F**ine **G**reen **S**ilk?
- **D**umb **K**ids **P**refer **C**heese **O**ver **F**ried **G**reen **S**pinach
- **D**o **K**indly **P**lace **C**over **O**n **F**resh **G**reen **S**pring **V**egetables
- **D**onald **K**ills **P**eople **C**ause **O**ther **F**riends **G**et **S**ad

Given the current political situation I would go with the last one but it is up to your personal preferences. You can as well make up your own. Mnemonics are like soups; it is always better when homemade. For example, extending upon the last and inspired by @John's comment, here is a homemade mnemonic

- **D**onald **K**idnaps **P**eople's **C**hildren **C**ausing **O**utlaw **F**oreigners **G**reat **S**uffering

Enjoy the game!

Comment: do kill purple clowns or face great suffering.